apollo-client use socks5 proxy
How to properly inject SOCKS5 proxy into Apollo GraphQL client?
export class MyFixture {
  private client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

  constructor() {
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: process.env.URL,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.TOKEN}`,
      },
    });
    
    // socks5://localhost:1081

    this.client = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      link: httpLink,
      typeDefs: myGraphQlSchema,
    });
  }
}


I assume somehow proxy agent needs to be injected into http link, but not sure how exactly
